# UNIX cut command by tab

Tags: bash, unix, cut

**Problem:**
Given a tab delimited file with several columns (tsv format) print the first three fields.

**Input** 
Tab seperated file with ASCII text

**Output:**
Contain N lines for each line in the inpu print 1st three fields.

**My Code:**

```
while read line; 
do
    echo $line | cut -f-3
done
```

**My Output:**

```
1 New York, New York[10] 8,244,910 1 New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA MSA 19,015,900 1 New York-Newark-Bridgeport, NY-NJ-CT-PA CSA 22,214,083
2 Los Angeles, California 3,819,702 2 Los Angeles-Long Beach-Santa Ana, CA MSA 12,944,801 2 Los Angeles-Long Beach-Riverside, CA CSA 18,081,569
3 Chicago, Illinois 2,707,120 3 Chicago-Joliet-Naperville, IL-IN-WI MSA 9,504,753 3 Chicago-Naperville-Michigan City, IL-IN-WI CSA 9,729,825
4 Houston, Texas 2,145,146 4 Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX MSA 6,526,548 4 Washington-Baltimore-Northern Virginia, DC-MD-VA-WV CSA 8,718,083
5 Philadelphia, Pennsylvania[11] 1,536,471 5 Houston-Sugar Land-Baytown, TX MSA 6,086,538 5 Boston-Worcester-Manchester, MA-RI-NH CSA 7,601,061
```

**Question:**
 I have looked everywhere for a solution for this.

Comment: Please paste the TSV file. How do you feed data into the while loop? Via `<`?

Comment: @Corion why? `cut` does that by default

Comment: @Rafael Ah - I thought it split on any whitespace, but you are correct!

Comment: Just FYI this specific problem comes up on HackerRank, and I've encountered the same problem, the default delimiter is not working. I think the input might be malformed. You have to go line by line the way HackerRank works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a solution use the following:
  `cut -d$'\t' -f1-3`

If you are confused on what the flags look here:

- `-d` = for delimiter
- `$'\t'` = looking for the tab escape character
- `-f1-3` = field number 1 through 3. aka only prints first 3 words.

For more information look here: [Cut Command Linux](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cut-command-linux-examples/)

Comment: tab is cut's (from GNU coreutils) default delimiter.

Comment: Special strings like `$'string'` are meaningless to most shells. [This is a bash feature.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) However, using `cut`'s default TAB delimiter, [is defined in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (thus portable).

Answer (score 4):

Why not just?:

```
cut -f1-3 data.tsv
```